# cv::namedWindow() hangs when called

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I am using Netbeans C++ to create a small project.  I have this simple code:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cv::namedWindow("Output");

    // Create Receiver and Decoder on another thread
    boost::thread t1 = boost::thread(startReceiver); // Details irrelevant
    boost::thread t2 = boost::thread(startDecoder);  // Details irrelevant

    std::cout << "Waiting..." << std::endl;

    t2.join();
    t1.join();

    std::cout << "Finished." << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The program hangs on `cv::namedWindow("Output");`.  I have paused the program using GDB and this is the call stack:

```cpp
poll ()
?? ()
xcb_connect_to_fd ()
xcb_connect_to_display_with_auth_info ()
_XConnectXCB ()
XOpenDisplay ()
gdk_display_open ()
gdk_display_open_default_libgtk_only ()
gtk_init_check ()
gtk_init ()
cvInitSystem ()
cvNamedWindow ()
main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe4c8)
```

It is polling for something, I don't know what...  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a problem related to GTK. Try to use a standard window:

```
cv::namedWindow("Output", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL|CV_GUI_NORMAL);
```

Comment: That resolves the hanging for that call, but now when I call `cv::imshow("Output", img);` within one of the boost threads it hangs....

Comment: It's generally not allowed to try to display things on the screen in a thread different from the main thread. I don't know the implementation of `imshow`, but it's probably the problem here. Try to call `imshow` from the main thread.

Comment: Okay thanks.  Marking you as correct since you did solve this problem, I'll have to post another question for the threading one...